# Get first non null value in a partition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, non-nullable, first-value

As SQL Server does not support ignore nulls in `first_value` function, how can we get the first non null value in a window without defining a new column?

I tried to use `COALESCE()`, however it didn't work as a window function.

Comment: SQL Server supports ignore_nulls as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#-ignore-nulls--respect-nulls-)  in the current version

Comment: What does "non-nullable" have to do with the question here?Even *with* `IGNORE NULLS` using `FIRST_VALUE` on a `NULL`able column won't result in a non-`NULL`able expression. If *all* the values in the range/rows are `NULL` then `FIRST_VALUE` will return `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned, `FIRST_VALUE` does support `IGNORE NULLS` (in SQL Server 2022+). As such you *can* do:

```sql
FIRST_VALUE(YourColumn) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY SomeColumn ORDER BY AnotherColumn) AS FirstValue
```

Emulating this for `FIRST_VALUE` isn't too difficult without the syntax though, just add a `CASE` to your `ORDER BY` on your column to order the `NULL` values later:

```sql
FIRST_VALUE(YourColumn) OVER (PARTITION BY SomeColumn ORDER BY CASE WHEN YourColumn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, OtherColumn)
```

This'll force values that *are* `NULL` to be ordered later and so can only be the first value if all the values are `NULL`.